# Cambiar el codigo de un Navigation Drawer Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragment, clase

Estoy usando un  **Navigation Drawer Activity** pero quiero cambiarle los nombres a los Layout que le da android por defecto así como en las clases, **personificar su contenido**. Para poder trabajar con ellos sin que me salten errores.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código que quieres cambiar? ¿Qué es lo que quieres cambiar? ¿Qué errores tienes?

Comment: Agrega lo que trataste o investigaste, por favor, revisar [ask], de otra forma si necesitas una opinión, puedes realizarlo en [chat], saludos.